# Simulate MATLAB's meshgrid function

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, function-construction, matlab

[Here](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) is MATLAB's `meshgrid`. I came up with these implementations in *Mathematica*:

```
{x, y} = With[{n = 10}, Table[#, {i, n}, {j, n}]] & /@ {j, i};
```

and

```
{x, y, z} = Array[List, {5, 5, 5}][[All, All, #]] & /@ {3, 2, 1}
```

but it seems that it's not fast enough. The following example is about three times slower than MATLAB.

```
(* Mathematica *)
(
  {a, b} = With[{n = 3000}, Table[#, {i, n}, {j, n}]] & /@ {j, i};
  c = a^2 + b^2 // N // Sqrt;
  Compile[{}, Position[Unitize@FractionalPart@c, 0]][] // Length
) // AbsoluteTiming
```

```matlab
%MATLAB
tic;
[a,b]=meshgrid(1:3000);
c=sqrt(a.^2+b.^2);
idx=find(c==round(c));
length(idx)
toc;
```

Can you recommend an efficient method?

**Updated**

```
(
  {a, b} = {#, Transpose@#} &@ConstantArray[Range@3000, {3000}];
  c = Sqrt@N[a*a + b*b];
  SparseArray[Unitize@FractionalPart@c~BitXor~1]["NonzeroPositions"] // Length
) // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: For those of us who do not use Matlab can you describe what the meshgrid function does ...rather than forcing us to infer it by examining your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(**Update**, added more points, and more timings)

Using [MATLAB's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) help standard example for meshgrid:

#### Mathematica implementation

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List]:={ConstantArray[x,Length[x]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[y]]}

{xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, .1], Range[-4, 4, .2]];
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2];

pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, c}, {2, 3}];
ListPlot3D[pts, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
           ImagePadding -> 20, Mesh -> 35, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
           ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]
```

#### MATLAB

```
    [X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.1:2, -4:.2:4);
    Z = X .* exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);
    surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

MATLAB timing was done using this template code by changing the grid spacing, as an example for the code that generate the above plot:

```
tic;  [X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2, -4:.4:4); toc
```

Mathematica was done on this template

```
Timing[
 {xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, .2], Range[-4, 4, .4]];
 ][[1]]
```

### Table of timings

The timing were done for different grid sizes as in (.2,.4) pairs in the above example and using Mathematica 9.01 and MATLAB 2012a, all on Windows 7. I could not do smaller grids than shown in the table below, else I ran out of memory. All times are in seconds. Same PC. 16 GB [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), Intel [Core i7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica's above implementation of meshgrid using `ConstantArray` seems to be a little slower as the number of grid points increased. A faster implementation should be investigated.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think `ListPlot3D[Transpose[c],...]` is enough.

Comment: I think `Flatten[Transpose[{xx, yy, c}, {3, 1, 2}], 1] == 
 Flatten[Map[Part, Transpose[{xx, yy, c}, {3, 1, 2}], {2}], 1]`.

Comment: @ruebenko yes that will work, but it will not include the actual x and y coordinates. It will only display the z-cordinates and will use for the x,y coordinates the number of points. I wanted it to be like with Matlab's where the x,y axis has the actual coordinate ticks.

Comment: @explorer yes, you are right, I did not need Map in there. Yours is simpler. Will update now. thanks.

Comment: You could also use `pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, c}, {2, 3}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods thanks! that is even simpler. Just updated. I must say I find Matlab little easier when it comes to this part. Matlab wants each coordinates in one separate vector, so one passes 3 separate vectors, while Mathematica wants the coordinates in a matrix (each row has each `{x,y,z}` coordinate). I never understood why can't there be 2 API's for this in Mathematica. Where the user can choose to pass the coordinates as `{X...},{Y...},{Z..}` vs `{{X,Y,Z}...}`, and let the user choose the simple one depending. What is so hard about having two different interfaces like this for the command?

Comment: You can also use `ListPlot3D[Transpose@c, DataRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: At large `n` I think it's more efficient to build the list via `Map` than to `Transpose` it. i.e. use `Map[ConstantArray[#, Length[y]] &, y]` instead of `Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length@y]`. It's not much better, but it does give a second or so of improvement when you have 15000 mesh points in both x and y

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but shouldn't the meshgrid function should be defined as `{ConstantArray[x,Length[y]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[x]]}`, so that the two output arrays have the same dimensions?

Answer (score 8):

**Concise**

Another way to define `meshgrid()` in Mathematica is:

```
meshgrid[xgrid_List, ygrid_List] := Transpose[Outer[List, xgrid, ygrid], {3, 2, 1}]
```

It's definitely not winning the speed competition (about 10x slower than rm -rf's solution), but speaks more for Mathematica's language, which allows neat and concise definitions like this.

**Speed**

Regarding speed, in your particular example you can do the squaring before the repetition via `ConstantArray`, loose the superfluous `N` in the computation of `c` and use `Count` instead of `Position[...]\\Length` to save computation time.

```
({a, b} = {#, Transpose@#} &@ConstantArray[N@Range@3000, {3000}];
 c = a^2 + b^2 // N // Sqrt;
 Compile[{}, Position[Unitize@FractionalPart@c, 0]][] //Length) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.698965,7388} *)

({asq, bsq} = {#, Transpose@#} &@ ConstantArray[N[Range[3000]]^2, {3000}];
 c = Sqrt[asq + bsq];
 Compile[{}, Count[Unitize@FractionalPart@c, 0, 2]][]) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.396491,7388} *)
```

Comment: (+1) I contemplated posting the same thing using `Outer` (which IMO is the clearest way to think about tensored grids) but I noticed that this turned into a speed chase and got discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

`meshgrid()`'s functionality is easily handled by `ConstantArray`. For the example you provided (i.e. `meshgrid` called with a single vector),

```
{a, b} = {#, Transpose@#}&@ConstantArray[N@Range@3000, {3000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.068030, Null} *)
```

You can easily extend it to handle the two argument case by calling `ConstantArray` for each list (`x` and `y`) and using the length of the other list as the number of repetitions, which I'll leave for you to implement.

Comment: This brings down the time from ~0.9s to ~0.5s on my system. Still slower than MATLAB... I think an explicit `Position` finder (i.e., using `Do` loops) that is compiled to C in _Mathematica_ might speed things up a bit more...

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer excellent and comprehensive, but it has a very fine/little mistake\bug. I've tried to fix it, but it has to be accepted due to my current reputation(=101) on this site(well, I'm not very active here), and mistakenly it was not. The mistake is in the correct treatment of lists of different sizes.
I'll explain in more details...

consider two implementations, the first (`meshgrid1`) is copied from current version (as of 2/2/2018) of the accepted answer, the second (`meshgrid2`) is a correctly reproduces matlab's meshgrid. The little difference is in the argument of `Length`.

```
meshgrid1[x_List, y_List]:={ConstantArray[x,Length[x]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[y]]}

meshgrid2[x_List, y_List]:={ConstantArray[x,Length[y]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[x]]}
```

now use it in a slightly different example then in the accepted answer (the `ylist` here is not the same size as `xlist`)

```
xlist = Range[-2, 2, .1];   
ylist = Range[-4, 4, .1];   
Length[xlist] 
Length[ylist] 

Out: 41
Out: 81
```

and see the dimensions of the result

```
{xx1, yy1} = meshgrid1[xlist, ylist];   
Dimensions[xx1] 
Dimensions[yy1] 

Out: {41, 41} 
Out: {81, 81}
```

and

```
{xx2, yy2} = meshgrid2[xlist, ylist];
Dimensions[xx2] 
Dimensions[yy2]

Out: {81, 41}
Out: {81, 41}
```

now the same thing in matlab - decide by yourself which one is correct or make more sense

```
>> xlist = -2:.1:2; 
>> ylist = -4:.1:4;
>> [xx,yy] = meshgrid(xlist, ylist);

>> size(xlist)

ans =

     1    41

>> size(ylist)

ans =

     1    81
size(xx)

ans =

    81    41

>> size(yy)

ans =

    81    41
```

Comment: Good job on debugging. The accepted answer probably got confused since the two starting vectors happened to be the same length, so the wrong lengths being supplied was not noticed. Had a rectangular plotting region been used like in your case, the error would have been spotted more quickly.

Comment: This answer should be accepted and be seen by more people who really want to use the meshgrid fucntions.