# How to draw a graph about the FourierTransform of a 2D Function?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

Here is a 2D function, and it cannot be calculated by the `FourierTransfrom`

```
n = 2; δ = 0.2;
p[x_, y_] = Cosh[n*Sqrt[2 Pi]*δ*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]*Exp[-((δ^2*(x^2 + y^2) + 2 n^2*Pi)/2)];

p[x,y] ContourPlot
```

[image]

and my problem is how to draw a graph about its `FourierTransform` Function?

Here is an example:
if I have a function that can be calculated by `FourierTransform` like below:

```
n = 2; δ = 0.2;
p[x_, y_] = Cosh[n*Sqrt[2 Pi]*δ*x]*Cosh[n*Sqrt[2 Pi]*δ*y]*Exp[-((δ^2*x^2+ 2 n^2*Pi)/2)]*Exp[-((δ^2*y^2+ 2 n^2*Pi)/2)];
uu1[tx_, ty_] = FourierTransform[p[x, y], {x, y}, {tx, ty}];
ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}]
ContourPlot[uu[tx, ty]^2, {tx, -0.5, 0.5}, {ty, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

we will get the answer below:

[image]

And here, I suppose the function p[x,y] can not use `FourierTransform` ,I can use the function `Fourier`

```
data = Table[p[x, y], {x, -40, 40, 0.4}, {y, -40, 40, 0.4}];
ListDensityPlot[Re[Fourier[data]]]
```

[image]

but the answer is not I wanted! I don't know why? and I hope I can get help from you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing two things:

- Quadrant swapping, to put the low frequency components of the FFT at the centre of the array (look up Matlab's [fftshift](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) function for more information)
- Zero padding, which effectively interpolates between data points in the transformed domain and helps to reduce the "crosshair" effect you can see in Nasser's results. See e.g. [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/741) for more details

E.g.

```
data = Table[p[x, y], {x, -40, 40, 1}, {y, -40, 40, 1}];

(* pad array with zeros - here I am padding to 1024x1024 *)
data = ArrayPad[data, {#, 1024 - Length[data] - #} &[512 - Round[Length[data]/2]]];

(* FFT with quadrant swapping *)
result = Re @ With[{qs = RotateRight[#, {512, 512}] &}, qs @ Fourier @ qs @ data];

(* Cut out the interesting part of the data and plot it *)
ListContourPlot[ArrayPad[result, -400]^2]
```

[image]

Comment: This code works, Thanks a lot!

Comment: but I don't understander qs @ Fourier @ qs @ data

Answer (score 2):

ps. I tried to get the symbolic Fourier, but gave up. Too hard to do this symbolically.

```
expr = p[x, y] /. {n -> 2, del -> 0.5};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FourierTransform[expr, {x, y}, {w1, w2}]
```

Not working.... So, try numerical FFT. Using [meshgrid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30701/simulate-matlabs-meshgrid-function/30706#30706) and pick some spatial x,y frequencies, which I am not sure now if it meets spatial Nyquist or not. Then using FFT (Fourier) on the 2D image.

```
n = 2; del = 0.5;

p[x_, y_] = Cosh[n*Sqrt[2 Pi]*del*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]* Exp[-((del^2*(x^2 + y^2) + 2 n^2*Pi)/2)];

meshgrid[x_List, y_List]:={ConstantArray[x, Length[x]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[y]]}

{xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-4 Pi, 4 Pi, .05], Range[-4 Pi, 4 Pi, .05]];
c = p[xx, yy];

ListPlot3D[Transpose@c, DataRange -> {{-4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {-4 Pi, 4 Pi}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[c];
d = c*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
fw = Fourier[d, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
(*adjust for better viewing as needed*)
fudgeFactor = 10;
abs = fudgeFactor*Log[1 + Abs@fw];
Labeled[Image[abs/Max[abs], ImageSize -> 300],Style["Magnitude spectrum", 18]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you use different sampling in the above meshgrid, resolution of the 2D looking spectrum will change, like this (these are all centered so that center of spectrum is DC frequency).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
arg = Arg@fw;
Labeled[Image[arg/Max[arg], ImageSize -> 300],Style["Phase spectrum", 18]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]