# ListContourPlot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, matlab

I tried to plot the following curves in Mathematica using "ListContourPlot" , and compared them with the results from Matlab 2019a.

**Mathematica code: (*cite from Reference (1)*)**

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]]}

{xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, 0.1], Range[-4, 4, 0.2]];
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2];

pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, c}, {2, 3}];

ListContourPlot[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica results]

**Matlab code:**

```
x = linspace(-2,2,40);
y = linspace(-4,4,40);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X .* exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);
contourf(X,Y,Z,10)
```

[image: Matlab results]

The plotting effects from both softwares are not the same.

My question is how can we have the ContourPlot effects (this example) like those in Matlab?

References:

(1). [Simulate MATLAB's meshgrid function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30701/simulate-matlabs-meshgrid-function)

(2). [Filled 2-D contour plot](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html)

Comment: how about `ListContourPlot[pts, PlotRange -> All,   Contours -> 10, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]`?

Comment: @kglr this methd is not good, because two eclipses are too small...

Comment: try also the option `Contours -> DeleteCases[0][Subdivide[-3, 3, 10]/10]`?

Comment: @kglr thanks a lot for your suggestion, it is imporved, but the external circles are still too small, you may take a look at the matlab plot results.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM `ListContourPlot[pts, PlotRange -> All, 
 Contours -> DeleteCases[0][Subdivide[-3, 3, 10]/10], 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`

Comment: @cvgmt thanks for your answer! but how to have the external circle near the Cartesian coordinates in mathematica?

Comment: `meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]]}

{xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-1.9, 1.9, 0.1], Range[-3.8, 3.8, 0.2]];
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2];

pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, c}, {2, 3}];

ListContourPlot[pts, PlotRange -> All, 
 Contours -> DeleteCases[0][Subdivide[-3, 3, 10]/10], 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]`

Comment: @cvgmt  the external circles are still not near the  cartesian y coordinate, in Matlab, the external circles are near the  cartesian y coordinate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is something you want to get:

```
scaling = 0.80;
ListContourPlot[
  pts,
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",
  Contours -> Subdivide[scaling Min[Last /@ pts], scaling Max[Last /@ pts], 9],
  AspectRatio -> 0.8
]
```

[image]

Comment: in addition, is there a mathematica command like "meshgrid" in matlab?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Are you looking for `Outer[List, array1, array2]` or `CoordinateBoundsArray`?

Comment: @b3m2a1  I got the point that you mean for this question! thanks!

Comment: **Is there a mathematica command like "meshgrid" in matlab?** ClearAll["Global`*"] meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]]} {xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, 0.1], Range[-4, 4, 0.2]]; c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2]; pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, c}, {2, 3}]; Using `CoordinateBoundsArray` grid = Transpose@CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-2, 2}, {-4, 4}}, {0.1, 0.2}]; c1 = Apply[#1 Exp[-#1^2 - #2^2] &, grid, {2}]; pts1 = Flatten /@ Flatten[{grid, c1}, {2, 3}]; Using `Outer` grid2 = Transpose@Outer[List, Range[-2, 2, 0.1], Range[-4, 4, 0.2]]; c2 = Apply[#1 Exp[-#

Comment: how to automatically find the scaling value?

Comment: Well, isn't this an answer for this question?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30701/1871

Comment: @a "in addition, is there a mathematica command like `meshgrid` in matlab?" Your question is confusing. You already found [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30701/1871), don't you?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100585)

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Actually, I found the scaling value by trial and error. In this case, `scaling = 0.8` approximately gives `Subdivide[-0.35, 0.35, 9]`.

Comment: @xzczd In this case, a "command" of mathematica just means  a command (e.g. word), not (few) line(s) codes. Moreover, This post is in 2013, and in 2021 we can use 12.3. version of mathematica...

Comment: @tueda good to know, thank you!

Comment: @a The last answer for that question is added in 2018. If you suspect the answer there is outdated, consider starting a bounty for it.